# Block users for using Runinvoker command to run applications requiring administrator privileges

Tags: security, command-line, uac, group-policy, gpo

I am working in a company as IT guy. I was wondering if there is a way to prevent users for using the following command in order to launch application that require administrator rights.

```
cmd /min /C “set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER && start “” %1″
```

What RunAsInvoker does is to ignore any elevation request in the application’s manifest.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem you are trying to solve. What's wrong with users invoking a command and ignoring the elevation request?

Comment: Any user knowing this command can run on his computer any setup he wants. Since our users have no local admin on their computer due to security purpose, this command is a workaround for running any exe bypassing elevation request.

Comment: Ignoring the elevation request doesn't mean the command will run as administrator. It means the command will proceed run with limited permissions. (If it was that easy to bypass UAC, all malware would have to do is set that environment variable and do whatever they wanted.)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `__COMPAT_LAYER` environment variable to `RunAsInvoker` does not mean that programs will automatically run elevated without a UAC prompt. It means that an executable won't prompt for administrative credentials even if it has a manifest that specifies it should run as administrator.

Source: [Is RunAsInvoker a secret, even higher UAC setting?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20161117-00/?p=94735)

Excerpt:

> Actually, `RunAsInvoker` is a secret, even *lower* UAC setting.
>
> What `RunAsInvoker` does is to ignore any elevation request in the application's manifest and treat the manifest as if it had said
>
> `<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />`
>
> which is the default behavior. The program simply runs with the same privileges as the code that launched it. There is no attempt to elevate.
>
> This means that if you run the program from an elevated command prompt, then the program stays elevated. If you run the program from a non-elevated command prompt, then the program stays non-elevated.